# Arabic Characters are not recognised in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Did anyone face this issue before, I pushed an Arabic document to elasticsearch and when I get it back all the chars inside it are coming in a wired format, not even Unicode escaped. see below. does anyone know what the issue is?

```
{
    "script": 
    {
        "phrases": 
        [
            {
                "phrase": "'(H 'DE:J+ B/3 'DDG 1H-G (4J! H'DB/3 'DDG '-E/ E1*6I",
                "alternativePhrases": [
                    "'(H 'DE:J+ B/3 'DDG 1H-G (4J! H'DB/3 'DDG '-E/ E.*'1",
                    "'(H 'DE:J+ B/3 'DDG 1H-G (4J! H'DB/3 'DDG '-F' AJ 7'('",
                    "'(H 'DE:J+ B/3 'DDG 1H-G (4J! 'DB/3J 'DDG '-E/ E.*'1",
                    "'(H 'DE:J+ B/3 'DDG 1H-G (4J! 'DB/3 'DDG '-E/ E1*6I"
                ]
            },
            {
                "phrase": " E' 5-G 'D/9'! D'-/",
                "alternativePhrases": [
                    " E' 5-G 'D/9'! 9DI '-/",
                    " E3-* 'D/9'! D'-/",
                    " E' 5-G 'D/9'! D' '-/",
                    " E' 5-G 'D/9'! H'D'-/"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This was the original document (note: not exact same text though)

```
{
    "script": 
    {
        "phrases": 
        [
            {
                "phrase": " اغنيه عن اب ليس فقط عن العين",
                "alternativePhrases": [
                    " غريب عين ابليس سقط عن العين",
                    " غير عين ابليس سقط عن العين",
                    " غير عين ابليس فقط عن العين",
                    " غريب عين ابليس فقط عن العين"
                ]
            },
            {
                "phrase": " كشاف على العين العين بالاحكام",
                "alternativePhrases": [
                    " كشاف على العين العين من له احكام",
                    " كشف الهوى العين العين من له احكام",
                    " كشاف على العين العيب من له احكام",
                    " كشاف على العين العين من الاحكام"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, this is the index mapping:

```
PUT _template/ar-template
{
    "index_patterns": 
    [
        "*ar-idx*"
    ],
    "mappings": 
    {
        "doc": 
        {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": 
            {
                "script": 
                {
                    "properties": 
                    {
                        "phrases": 
                        {
                            "properties": 
                            {
                                "alternativePhrases": 
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": 
                                    {
                                        "keyword": 
                                        {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "endTime": 
                                {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                },
                                "phrase": 
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": 
                                    {
                                        "keyword": 
                                        {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "startTime": 
                                {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": 
    {
        "index": 
        {
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "refresh_interval": "30s",
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May you show an example of the document before insertion to ES?

Comment: I have modified the original post to include the document as well as index pattern

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce. Copy-pasting the doc and inserting works for me (ES 6.0). I managed to obtain similar encoding corruption by: 1) saving doc in utf8 file, 2) converting the file into cp1256, 3) doing `cat file.json | pbcopy`, 4) pasting it into Postman, 5) executing POST. Please check that you send correct utf8 document to ES.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay Vasiliev, I am sending this header in the _bulk method, is that correct?

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: I am not talking about the header, I am talking about the actual data being transferred. To debug this situation it will help you to answer questions like: where does the data come from? Is it in utf8 in the data source? How does it travel from source to the HTTP request? (do you copy-paste it?) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tokenizers to convert your Arabic inputs to Unicode.
For instance in ELK documentation a tokenizer is illustrated to convert Arabic literals to equivalent Latin.
Create an index template and include these tokenizers and filters.

Here is the link to the documentation I refereed to:
[Elastic Search Unicode Character Folding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/character-folding.html)